# jQuery event delegation with select elements?

Tags: jquery, debugging, html-select, onchange, event-delegation

While doing some sanity tests I noticed that the following `change` event binding works:

```
$("body").on("change","input", function(){console.log(1)})
```

While the `on` event binding does not:

```
$("body").on("change","select", function(){console.log(1)})
```

Is there any workaround or explanation for this inconsistency?

Comment: Can you explain it better ? Maybe with some demo.

Comment: Is it specific to a particular browser?

Comment: Works for me in chrome http://jsfiddle.net/eHRCD/

Comment: better run that sanity check again.. works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the Event Listeners panel in the Elements tab of the Developer Toolbar, I discovered the root cause. There were two delegated change events both bound to the same `select` element which was wrapped inside a `div` container for styling. The event bound to the inner container returned false, which stopped propagation to the event bound to the outer container. I realized the inner binding was overkill, so I removed it to solve the problem.

**References**

- [Viewing element event listeners](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/dom-and-styles#viewing-element-event-listeners)
- [Chromium Devtools Blog](http://blog.chromium.org/search/label/devtools)
- [Selectmenu Widget | jQuery UI API Documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/selectmenu/)